# Jquery Add Image To External Links Exclude Subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm using the following line to add a custom font character next to my link text to indicate that the link is external if it is.

`$('a[href*="://"],[target="_blank"],[href^="#"],[href^="mailto:"]').append(' <span class="external">&#0064;</span>');`

I recently added a gallery to my webpage and the images are pulled from a subdomain [http://img.example.com] and the images are wrapped inside of anchor tags for a scroll gallery.

Since the images are linked to a subdomain my jQuery adds the special character next to the images.

I tried the following to exclude the `img` subdomain but it didn't work.

`$('a[href*="://"],[target="_blank"],[href^="#"],[href^="mailto:"]').not('[href^="img"]').append(' <span class="external">&#0064;</span>');`

I'm not very familiar with jQuery so I'm not entirely sure where my mistake is or how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure you have it right, but maybe the selector in the `.not()` isn't working properly? What about `[href*="://img"]`?

Comment: That did the trick. :) Thanks